# Writing a generic Resolver in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, generics, mapping, automapper

I wanna write a Generic AutoMapper's Resolver for changing Model's file path.
Without Generic Resolver, I've written the following resolver :
e.g:

```
public class UserPhotoPathResolver : ValueResolver<User, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(User source)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        return url.Content(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.PhotoPath) 
            ? StaticVariables.DefaultUserImagePath 
            : source.PhotoPath);
    }
}
```

Now, I've written the following Resolver :

```
public class FilePathResolver<T, TProperty> : ValueResolver<T, string> where T : class
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> _propertyExpression;

    public FilePathResolver(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        _propertyExpression = propertyExpression;
    }

    protected override string ResolveCore(T source)
    {
        Type typeOfEntity = typeof(T);

        MemberExpression member = _propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.", _propertyExpression));

        PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.", _propertyExpression));

        if (typeOfEntity != propInfo.ReflectedType && !typeOfEntity.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expresion '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.", _propertyExpression, typeOfEntity));

        string filePath = Convert.ToString(ModelHelpers.GetStringPropertyValue(source, propInfo.Name));
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)
            ? string.Empty
            : UrlHelpers.GetUrlHelperInstance().Content(filePath);
    }
}

public static object GetStringPropertyValue(object src, string propertyName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(src, null);
}

public static TProperty GetValue<T, TProperty>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null) return default(TProperty);
    Func<T, TProperty> func = expression.Compile();
    return func(obj);
}
```

But `FilePathResolver` returns this string `MyApp.Classes.Helpers.FilePathResolver%602[MyApp.DAL.ModelName,System.String]`

I'm using this resolver as the following :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityClass, EntityClassModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.ResolvedLogoPath, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(m => new FilePathResolver<EntityClass, string>(p => p.LogoPath)));
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please post `ModelHelpers.GetStringPropertyValue` content. Looks like the problem is somewhere in its implementation.

Comment: @k0stya It's written at the of Middle Code Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that wrong ResolveUsing method overload is used.

[image]

But you need the following one.

[image]

You can fix it by changing mapping configuration in the following way.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityClass, EntityClassModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.ResolvedLogoPath, 
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FilePathResolver<EntityClass, string>>()
        .ConstructedBy(() => new FilePathResolver<EntityClass, string>(p => p.LogoPath)));
```

Or even like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityClass, EntityClassModel>()
  .ForMember(m => m.ResolvedLogoPath, 
    opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new FilePathResolver<EntityClass, string>(p => p.LogoPath)));
```